# Does each e.g. wordpress subdomain have a unique IP?

Tags: wordpress, url-routing

Webhosting sites like wordpress or godaddy have several subdomains like https://hello.wordpress.com/ . Does each of them have a unique IP-address (v4 or v6)? If not, how does routing work?

I just checked and the output from `host hello.wordpress.com` equals `host www.wordpress.com`. So I assume that...

- [www.wordpress.com](http://www.wordpress.com) resolves to e.g. `192.0.78.12/` and
- hello.wordpress.com resolves to e.g. `192.0.78.12/hello` or similar.

Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an A record for each subdomain, so you can point it to the same IP address or a different one.

The routing of the sites is just done with the server configuration, I can't speak for GoDaddy or WordPress as I don't know what stack they are using.

I believe a standard Apache server would have the main domain in `/public_html` and the subdomain in a `/sub.domain.com` folder.